# Consolidating procedural code to an associative array object

Tags: javascript

I have 5 functions that check user input against regular expressions...these regular expressions have been abstracted out and put here as suggested in [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8042289/edit).

Now I want to abstract out the functionality and put the code into an associative array per the previous post as well..however their seemed to be some contention as to whether this is best practice? Is this O.K to do?

Is it good practice to put these functions into an associative array of functions?  The previous post doing this is not up..as I'm guessing they decided against it.

But basically how to do you group similar methods together properly.

```
EDIT 1: // consolidated regular expressions

var patterns = {   
  name: /^[a-zA-Z-\s]{1,20}$/, 
  email: /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{1,4}$/,
  pass: /.{6,40}/,
  url:  /^[-\w&:\/\.=\?,#+]{1,}$/,
  aml:  /<(.+)_([a-z]){1}>$/
}; 

// checks full name which allows characters and dashes

function check_name(text,id,res) 
  {
  for(var d=0;d<=0;d++)
    {
    if(!patterns["name"].exec(text.value))
      {
      o2(id,res);
      return 0;
      }
    }
    return 1;
  }

// checks for valid email form

function check_email(text,id,res)
  {
  if(!patterns["email"].exec(text.value))
    {
    o2(id,res);
    return 0;
    }
  return 1;
  }

// checks for password length

function check_pass(text,id,res)
  {
  if(!patterns["pass"];.exec(text.value))
    {
    o2(id,res);
    return 0;
    }
  return 1;
  }

// checks for valid url form

function check_url(text,id,res)
  {
  if(!patterns["url"].exec(text.value))
    {
    o2(id,res);
    return 0;
    }
  return 1;
  }

// checks for aml form

function check_aml(text)
  {  
  if(a=patterns["aml"].exec(text))
    {
    if(a[2]=='p')
      {
      return 0;
      }
    else if (a[2]=='f')
      {
      return 1;
      }
    }
  else
    {
    return 2;
    }
  }
```

Comment: You might want to proofread your post...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there are any issues with creating a common place to store your patterns.  This in fact seems like a good approach.  However I don't see the need to have your individual checking functions be made aware of the global storage.  They should instead be made simply aware of the pattern they are checking and the source against which they check.  If you take this approach your checking code can be dramatically simplified

```
var make_check = function (pattern) {
  return function (text, id, res) {
    if(!pattern.exec(text.value)) {
      o2(id,res);
      return 0;
    }

    return 1;
  };
};

var check_name = make_check(patterns.name);
var check_email = make_check(patterns.email);
var check_pass = make_check(patterns.pass);
var check_url = make_check(patterns.url);
```

Here I've removed the notion of the global storage from the checking function.  Since the rest of the code is so similar it can be abstracted out to a single method which is passed the pattern it's looking to match.

Comment: paterns.name can be used in place of patterns["name"]?

Comment: @ChrisAaker in general yes it can

Comment: this works...pattern.name...like you said..i'm having a hard time with passing the pattern...IE is telling me I have a reutrn statement outside a function when I clearly do not?...let me see..

Comment: @ChrisAaker sorry there was a syntax error in my sample. I've updated it to be correct

Comment: It all works...thank you...I had left out the function keyword but I I fixed it...thanks again

Comment: You could simplfiy it further if the type of check is passed to a single function rather than making separate functions for each check type.